# Is individual column and row-level encryption possible in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, encryption

I know about complete column level encryption techniques and complete database encryption. But is it possible to encrypt individual rows and columns in SQL Server?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Always Encrypted** feature of SQL Server 2016 onward supports individual column level encryption but not row level.

Instead of row level encryption, [Row Level Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-2017) feature of SQL Server supports restricting access of particular set of records in the table.

Thanks!